# Rails- not able to save user's password bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, password-hash, bcrypt-ruby

I have user model and controller, user has `password`, `password_confirmation`, and `password_digest` fields. I have used `bcrypt` ruby gem.

When I create user, I give all above mentioned fields and user gets created. But User's `password` wont be saved, it gets saved in the hex form in `password_digest` field.

If I want to edit just user's name and when I open edit user form, the form has `password` and `password_confirmation` fields are empty. I have to again give a new password to save the user which I don't want to.

`attr_accessor` didn't help.

Here's my user's controller:

```
   before_filter :authorize

   def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
     @user.password = params[:user][:password]
     @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
     @user.save!
     redirect_to users_path
    else
     flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_message
     render :new
    end
   end

  def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to user_path
   else
    render 'edit'
    flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
   end
  end

  private
  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :emp_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  rescue
  {}
  end
```

Heres my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 rolify
 require 'bcrypt'
 has_secure_password
 # other field validations here....
 validates :password, presence: true
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

And edit form:

```
<%#= other fields here..... %>
<%= f.label :Password_for_this_portal %>
<%= f.password_field :password, :class=>"form-control" %>
<%= f.label :Confirm_passsword_for_this_portal %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class=>"form-control" %>
# ..... submit button here
```

**How NOT to ask again for password change in edit user form?**

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work, you don't save the password in the database.  it's saved as a digest for security reasons.

Comment: You never save actual password, only digest. This way if your database is hacked, user passwords can't be recovered by hacker to infer other services password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has_secure_password` is designed to validate the `password` and `password_digest`. However, in Rails 4.x, there is an option to disable the `password` being validated with:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password :validations => false
end
```

You might be able to perform validations on `create` only, such as:

```
 validates :password, presence: true, :on => :create
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :create
```

Comment: Thanks Shannon, what if i want to validate for two methods: say "delete" and "create",  ":on" doesn't work for  two methods.